# Redirect page to first page when there is no more records in the nth page after deletion in cakephp 2

Tags: redirect, pagination, cakephp-2.x

i am new to cakephp ,I am unable to find a proper way to get the count of records in a page from a list.
I have a list of batches in my page with pagination limit of 20 records per page.I want to know how to check if the records in the current page is empty and then redirect to page 1 if there are no more records in the current page after deleting a record.

Answer (score 0):

When Paginator has no results, it throws the `NotFoundException`.
You need to use `try/catch` in your Controller and proceed with the required next steps:

```php
try {
  $this->set('results', $this->Paginator->paginate($this->modelClass));

} catch (NotFoundException $e) {
  return $this->redirect(array(
    'action' => 'index', 
    '?' => $this->request->query, 
    'page' => 1
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  return $this->redirect(array(
    'action' => 'index', 
    '?' => $this->request->query, 
    'page' => 1
  ));
}
```